# How do I stop Chrome associating 'http' with 'Amazon'

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

Currently whenever I try to search in Google Chrome using the omnibar, if my query starts with 'http' I get moved to searching Amazon.

Example: Suppose I can't remember what a particular HTTP status code is. I begin typing "http 200" into the omnibar. However, as soon as I press space after typing 'http', the omnibar incorrectly 'recognizes' this as Amazon, and sends the rest of the query '200' there.

**How can I break the association between the word 'http' and the search service 'Amazon' in Google Chrome?**

(There's no combination of keys which will 'cancel' the Amazon search - even cursoring down to Google Search will be cancelled if I then continue typing. The only work-around is to go to the Google homepage, which kind of defeats the point of the omnibar).

Comment: I typed "http 200" into Chrome's address bar and pressed enter. It opened http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=http+200 and the top result was Wikipedia's article "List of HTTP status codes".

Comment: Yep, I suspect it is something gone crazy specifically on this machine. Just wondered if there is something specific I can tweak before I try nuking the whole cache/install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Source: https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653

> 1. Click the wrench icon [image: wrench icon] on the browser toolbar.
> 2. Select `Options` (`Preferences` on Mac and Linux; `Settings` on a Chromebook).
> 3. Click the `Basics` tab.
> 4. Click `Manage search engines` in the "Search" section.
>
>    - **Remove a search engine**: Select the search engine from the list and click the x that appears at the end of the row.
>    - **Add a search engine**: Scroll to the bottom of the dialog and fill out the following fields:
>
>      - **Add a new search engine**: Enter a nickname for the search engine.
>      - **Keyword**: Enter the text shortcut you want to use for the search engine. Use the keyword to do [keyword searches](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95655).
>      - **URL**: Enter the web address for the search engine.
>    - **Edit a search engine**: Select the search engine from the list and click the field you want to modify.
>    - **Make a search engine default**: Select the search engine you want to use as your default search engine and click the `Make default` button that appears in the row.

Of particular interest is the *keyword*. Try editing the Amazon search, and taking a look in there. If you don't need the Amazon search, just deleting it would work too.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a search suggestion , remove it.

When the suggestion loads up, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, it removes the wrong entry.

Comment: Shift+Delete didn't work, but right-clicking on the suggested search took me to the list of search engines so I was able to delete it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go into `Settings` -> `Manage search engine` and then go through the list for other search engines and select the one with "Amazon" from there.

Answer (score -1):

Do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> after adding space in the URL bar.

Comment: this will work for mac